# Yii framework CHttpCookie expire property is not set properly

Tags: php, cookies, yii

In Yii framework I create a new cookie using the following code:

```
$newCookie = new CHttpCookie('_tracker' $campaignId);
$newCookie->expire = (time()+(60*60*24*30));//1 month
$newCookie->httpOnly = true;
Yii::app()->request->cookies['_tracker'] = $newCookie;
//var_dump($newCookie);exit;
```

When I `var_dump` `$newCookie` variable, I get the following output:

```
object(CHttpCookie)[66]
  public 'name' => string '_tracker' (length=8)
  public 'value' => string 'd0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940' (length=40)
  public 'domain' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'expire' => int 1438433074
  public 'path' => string '/' (length=1)
  public 'secure' => boolean false
  public 'httpOnly' => boolean true
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

So `expire` property of `$newCookie` object is set, and `httpOnly` property is set too.

On the next request, when I receive the cookie and `var_dump` it, I get the following result:

```
object(CHttpCookie)[19]
          public 'name' => string '_tracker' (length=8)
          public 'value' => string 'd0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940' (length=40)
          public 'domain' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'expire' => int 0
          public 'path' => string '/' (length=1)
          public 'secure' => boolean false
          public 'httpOnly' => boolean false
          private '_e' (CComponent) => null
          private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

The problem is that `expire` property is set to `0`, and `httpOnly` property is set to `false`. What is the cause?

**UPDATE 1:** When I examine the cookie in a browser (Google Chrome), cookie expiration time is set properly, as well as httpOnly property. Here is screenshot:

[image: Cookie value]

**Update 2:** This is what Microsoft says: "*The browser is responsible for managing cookies, and the cookie's expiration time and date help the browser manage its store of cookies. Therefore, although you can read the name and value of a cookie, you cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time. When the browser sends cookie information to the server, the browser does not include the expiration information.*"

As per this Microsoft's comment, this means that browser will not send cookie expiration time, and that is the reason why Yii is seting expire property of received cookie to 0.

Can someone confirm this asumption, and is this true for httpOnly property?